# Reproduce Lambek calculus notation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, logic, grammar

I'm trying to reproduce the following in my document:

[image]

But I can't find a way of doing it. The closer that I got was with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[inference]{semantic}
\begin{document}

\inference{
    \inference{
        \inference{ p \rightarrow p\;\;\;\;p\rightarrow 
p}{p \rightarrow p\;\;\;\;\;(p/p)p \rightarrow p}[(/ $\rightarrow$)]} 
{(p/p)p(p\backslash p) \rightarrow p}[$(\backslash \rightarrow)$]
}
{(p/p)p \rightarrow p/(p\backslash p)}
[($\rightarrow$ /).]

\end{document}
```

Which had a quite different result:

[image]

How can I reproduce correctly  the first image?

Comment: The `bussproofs` package may provide a better way to achieve this format.

Comment: See the LaTeX for Logicians site for other options.

Comment: `bussproofs` L4L user guide at http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/latex/BussGuide2.pdf. Extension package at http://www.ucalgary.ca/rzach/blog/2014/05/bpextra-entire-deductions-in-bussproofssty.html. Newer alternatives include `ebproof` and `prftree`.

Comment: The LaTeX for Logicians site is **the** place for logic stuff. Suggestions made on TeX SE are not generally as good as those made there. (TeX SE is good for many TeX things, but not great for logic.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a method with the `prftree` package:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{prftree}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \prftree[r]{$\scriptstyle(/ \rightarrow)$}
  {\prftree[r]{$\scriptstyle(\backslash \rightarrow)$}
    {\prfassumption{p \rightarrow p}} {\prftree[r]{$\scriptstyle(/ \rightarrow)$}{\prfassumption{p \rightarrow p}}{\prfassumption{p \rightarrow p}}{(p/p)p \rightarrow p}}
    {(p/p)p(p \backslash p) \rightarrow p}}
  {(p/p)p \rightarrow p/(p \backslash p)}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>prftree</code> solution]

Comment: +1 This looks like a great package.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, it does. I just found it on the L4L site. I am pretty sure it was not listed before, though maybe I missed it. (I had thought `ebproof` was the latest package of this kind.) Documentation seems to work pretty well. It would be nice to have a global option to set the font for rules rather than typing `\scriptstyle` all the time, but that's just detail.

Comment: @AlanMunn I guess the p->p are assumptions rather than axioms. At least, that's usually a theorem in the axiomatic systems I've seen. (But this is not my area.)

Comment: I like your statement "TeX SE is good for many TeX things, but not great for logic." because it can be read in many ways (+1 ;-)

Comment: Dwedodd @marmot yr union peth ;).